# How call a function in a callback function with nextcord python

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

```
@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[1061756784567656448])
async def oui(ctx):
    button = Button(label="A + 1", style=ButtonStyle.blurple)
    myview = View(timeout=180)
    myview.add_item(button)
    
    
    async def aurevoir(ctx):
        await ctx.send_message("aurevoir")
        
    
    async def bonjour(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("bonjour")
        await aurevoir(ctx)
        
    button = Button(label="A + 1", style=ButtonStyle.blurple)
    myview = View(timeout=180)
    myview.add_item(button)
        
    
    button.callback = bonjour
    await ctx.send(f"hello",view= myview)
```

The function "aurevoir" never sends the message, and I got a lot of errors like 'Context' object has no attribute 'send_message'.
I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you were passing the `ctx` object through - it'd be better to use the interaction object that `bonjour` gets when you press the button and using the `followup` property on the interaction to send the message.

```py
async def oui(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    await ctx.defer()
    button = Button(label="A + 1", style=ButtonStyle.blurple)
    myview = View(timeout=180)
    myview.add_item(button)
    
    async def aurevoir(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.followup.send("aurevoir")
        
    async def bonjour(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("bonjour")
        await aurevoir(interaction)
        
    button = Button(label="A + 1", style=ButtonStyle.blurple)
    myview = View(timeout=180)
    myview.add_item(button)
        
    button.callback = bonjour
    await ctx.followup.send("hello", view=myview)
```

I also added a `ctx.defer` and a `ctx.followup.send`.